# How to force user input to be "x" amount of numbers long? C#

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, user-input

"Create a program that will allow a user to input up to 24 students into an array ensuring that the student number is exactly 5 digits long."

I have my code set to populate my object array but i cant figure out how to force user input to be 5 digits long. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have tried experimenting with Regex but cant quite get a grasp on it.

Comment: Console, WinForms, ASP.NET, MVC? "Show me the code!"... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague...

If you are running in console mode, you can just check the number of digits input and reject it and keep looping until the user enters the correct number of digits.

If you are in a GUI setting, then you can just disable whatever controls allow the user to proceed next as long as the input control contains fewer than 5 digits.

Comment: Sorry, yes my program is going to be running in console mode.

Comment: Ok, then you definitely want to run this in a loop.  Some of the other posters provided good answers for how you would do the check itself.  So just embed that check in a while loop, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head

```
Regex r = new Regex("[0-9]{5}");
Match m = r.Match(Input);

if(m.Success) { ...}
```

[Regex.Match Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx)

Also, you'll find this useful [Introduction to Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/28hw3sce%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You could also check via regex if you had them all ready in a comma delimited string using

```
([0-9]{5}[,]?){1,24}
```

for example, would validate

> 12345,23456,345678" but not "1234,45678,23

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, and the additional reading materials. Those are helping me understand regex

Answer (score 0):

regex expression:

```
/[0-9]{5}/
```

surround your expression with '/',
[0-9] denotes a any digit from 0-9,
{5} denotes exactly 5 characters length.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply